# Is partitioning an external Western Digital drive really a risk? And what are the differences between similar model numbers?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

I've been looking at acquiring a new external drive.  In talking to the WD people, the representative said WD doesn't recommend partioning the drive.  He was pretty assertive about this.

Is there a reason why I would be told not to partition a drive from WD? It's  pretty common practice to partition a hard drive and I've never heard a warning from anyone about this so far.

So, edited error message I've gotten twice now since using this new partitioned drive with time machine. WD says its bc im using a partitioned drive and apple says not to have the other 2 partitions mounted at the same time when time machine is backing up....  This is all new to me - didn't know you weren't suppose to have more than 1 drive mounted on the back up disk!?!  I use to never see or get these error messages before this.  And I use to have a partitioned drive on my old Time Machine external drive pre - Catalina.
[image: error message]

From WD's website:
[image: WD info]

Also, can anyone tell me if there is a difference between these 2 models:

1. **WDBCKA0100HBK** (from WesternDigital)
2. **WDBCKA0100HBK-NESN** (from BestBuy)

I assume the suffix on the Best Buy one is just their product number, but I want to make sure their is no difference....
This was after the move and before the backups
[image: b4 backup]

files not showing after backup....
[image: missing files]
[image: missing files2]

Comment: "is this to just cover their butt or what?".. I can only guess so.  **This tells me not to purchase WD whenever possible**.  My personal guess is that they end up with a lot of support calls that the drive isn't as big as they say it is (due to multiple partitions).  What a bunch of hogwash!

Comment: ok, I guess its because of what just happened to me - maybe - all the moving to the new drive went well even though it took about 3 days, 1.9 TB.  Made some partitions and check all the stuff that was there from the transfer, all good and ii was able to get some files off.  did small incremental back up tonight and then came back right after to ck status of folders and they were all gone - or at least not showing - see above.  Unmounted and remounted and still not showing.  Had to unplug drive after shutting down and plug back in and restart and the stuff reappeared.  what the hell??

Comment: more fun - see added error message above.  Gotten this twice now.  WD says bc I have a partitioned drive and apple says its bc I have 2 other partitions mounted at the same time when time machine is backing up.

Answer (score 3):

> I was told not to partition the drive - he said WD doesn't recommend it ...  Is this to just cover their butt or what?

In a way, yes.  It's to mitigate an onslaught of Technical Support contacts because the user this drive is targeted to (the retail consumer) will create all sorts of partition schemes, screw up royally, then call Tech Support screaming about what utter garbage their drives are.

So, what does it do specifically?  It gives them an out.  They can ask the customer (or the customer volunteers) about "multiple partitions" and they can point to this and say "we warned you it could get corrupted;" and they would be correct.

#### Can you have multiple partitions?

Of course.  What is a [partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table)?  It's nothing more than data structure put on the hard drive to describe how the partitions are laid out on that disk. Personally, I have multiple volumes (partitions) on my Synology NAS that has WD hard drives in them. It's been running like that for years.  So, not only can they be configured with multiple partitions, but they're actually quite stable (they should be; they've been around since about the time the hard drive was invented).

#### So why the fuss?

Retail consumer users are not at all like pro-sumer or professional IT people.  They don't have the experience and what experience they do have is very "few and far between." There's a lot of knee jerk reaction to what they choose (like the layout of a drive's partition map) and then shortly after, they find out that what they did was incorrect then go through all sorts of bodges to remedy their mistake.  It's not a knock on them, it's just a fact.

They will take a drive that was partitioned half for a Mac with a GUID layout and formatted as JHFS+, then pickup a HOWTO on Linux where they read that someone suggests setting things up with an MBR scheme and ExFAT for compatibility.  They type in the commands they see and suddenly all the data they never backed up has fallen off the digital cliff.  When it all goes sideways, they will call, screaming, into WD Tech Support because the drive failed and they have no idea why.

#### Is there a Benefit to partitioning

It depends on what you're doing.  Will it give you a performance gain?  Not in this day and age with modern file systems like JHFS+, NTFS, ZFS, and whatever Linux uses (I'm a FreeBSD and Apple guy).  Most people really have no need for partitioning the drive, *which is why WD tells people not to.*  If you're sharing data across multiple platforms ExFAT's got you covered from Apple, to PC, to BSD and whatever Linux distro you happen to be using.

### TL;DR

There's no issue with regards to partitioning your drive.  If it's new, *plan it out* before setting it up.  You can't (I should say it's very difficult) to make changes to your partition on the fly - and this is where people get in trouble.

If you happen to want to change it (and I encourage people to try because it's a learning experience) ***backup your data first.***  If anything fails here, it won't be a WD issue. No backup = working without a net.

#### Bonus footage

Model numbers... speaking as a former product manager for a hardware manufacturer...  There really isn't any difference in the hardware. It's not uncommon for a manufacturer to create a product SKU specific to a certain reseller/retailer or a SKU with a promotional item or bundle - ever wonder why some retailers can guarantee the lowest price on an item and you can only seem to find that particular item at *that* particular retailer?  Here's your answer.   In this case, the product model number is identical except for the suffix (and it's not versioning) indicating that it's may be for the retail channel.

Answer (score 1):

> was told not to partition the drive - he said WD doesn't recommend it

That's pure rubbish and WD does no such thing.
Don't trust anything that this ignoramus told you.

I bought WD quite a few times and these are good disk.

> WD no. is WDBCKA0100HBK and BB no. is WDBCKA0100HBK-NESN

These slightly different names relate to the internal offer.
For example, the WDBCKA0100HBK-NE32 is offered with a gift 32 GB thumb drive
([link](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/questions/wd-easystore-10tb-external-usb-3-0-hard-drive-black/6278208)).

In the article
[What Hard Drive is in a Western Digital 10TB EasyStore](https://www.spxlabs.com/blog/2018/11/28/what-hard-drive-is-in-a-western-digital-10tb-easystore)
it is found that on the interior of the disk is actually found a rebranded
WD HGST Ultrastar He10.
Very likely this same drive is found inside all the flavors and offers of the
WDBCKA0100HBK.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why WD would recommend this as it is usually better to partition a drive (especially a large drive such as 10TB). There are many valid reasons to partition a large volume like this and it is common practice.

There are countless web articles about [how to format WD drives](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20format%20WD%20drives&oq=how%20to%20format%20WD%20drives&aqs=chrome..69i57.383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) so my presumption is that partitioning would be fine considering the widespread information on how to do it. I can also personally attest to having partitioned several WD drives without errors.

About the NSEN part of your question:

**N** = Sales Region: Pan-America

**E** = External

**SN** = Standard Packaging

So, the only difference between an EESN, a NESN, and a SESN (or any of the other xESN markings), is where the original vendor who received the drive is located... E being Europe, the Middle East and Africa, and S being Multi-City Asia. [SOURCE](https://community.wd.com/t/my-book-essential-2-tb-usb-3-0-wdbacw0020hbk-nesn-vs-sesn-drive-differences/2138/9)

Comment: I don't think your explanation about searching for files makes any sense. The only time that ever happens is last-resort data recovery – the entire disk is never scanned when looking for a file in normal operation. Only the filesystem's directory structure (MFT) needs to be scanned, and it scales with the number of files, not their size.

Comment: @user1686  I will remove that part of the answer then as the user didnt even ask about it.